# Reactivity of property changes of an object inside of an array

Tags: javascript, svelte

What's the proper way to trigger reactivity in svelte when I am updating a property of an object inside of an array that's then passed as a Component's prop?

```
let items = [{
   id: 1,
   name: 'first'
}, {
   id: 2,
   name: 'second'
}];

function findItem(id) {
   return items.find(item => item.id == id);
}

function modifyItem(id, changedProps) {
   let item = findItem(id);
   if(item) {
     Object.assign(item, changedProps);
     items = [...items]; // this does nothing
     console.log(items); // correctly displays the modified items array
  }
}

// ...

<MyList {items}/>
```

So I am passing down my `modifyItem` function. A child component then calls it and wants to update the `items` array. That works just fine, but the reactivity is not triggered (I assume because svelte doesn't recognize that an object in the array has been modified) so `MyList` is never re-rendered.

What's the "proper"/"correct" way of doing this? It seems a bit inefficient to `.map` the whole array just to create a new instance of the object and push it in. Any other way? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Here's a working example. The counter which is a property of an item in the array is incremented as expected.

App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import DisplayCounter from "./DisplayCounter.svelte";
    let items = [{text: 'hello', count: 0}];

    function incrementCounter() {
      items[0].count++;
      items = [...items];
  }
</script>

<button on:click={incrementCounter}>Click me</button>
<DisplayCounter {items} />
```

DisplayCounter.svelte:

```
<script>
    export let items = []
</script>

<div>{items[0].count}</div>
```

And here's the REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/9c20112f09284ba983bf598012705c56?version=3.19.1

Comment: You are right, it works. I found my problem: I was passing an object as prop to the "ListItem" and then destructing it directly in that component, which was not reactive. That's why I never saw the updates.

Comment: Glad you found it and understood the reason. Happy svelting!

Comment: @Fygo would you be able to expand on your solution here? I'm encountering something similar with an object where I am reassigning it (content = {...content}) but the view is not updating it

Comment: @Pete I am sorry, I actually don't remember anymore the specifics. But I think it was simply this: `export let obj;
 let notReactive = obj.date;
 $: reactive = obj.date;` (this would apply to destructuring as well)